# Let $H \le G$. Show that $N_G(H) \le \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H \}$ and if $H$ is finite then $N_G(H) = \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H \le G$. Show that $N_G(H) \le \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H \}$ and if $H$ is finite then $N_G(H) = \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$.

What has been done:

For $G$ and $H \le G$, it is defined
$$N_G(H) = \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} = H\} \subseteq G$$

Note that for $1 \in G$, $(1)H(1^{-1}) = H$. Thus $1 \in N_G(H) \neq \emptyset$.

Let $x \in N_G(H)$, then $x \in G$ and $xHx^{-1}=H$. In particular, $xHx^{-1} \le H$. Thus, $x \in \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$.

Let's see that $N_G(H) \le \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$.

Let $x, y \in N_G(H)$. Since $y \in N_G(H)$ and $N_G(H) \le G$, $y^{-1} \in N_G(H)$. By the other hand, since $N_G(H) \le G$ and $x, y^{-1} \in N_G(H)$, $xy^{-1} \in N_G(H)$. Thus, $N_G(H) \le \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$.

It is necessary to prove that $\{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\} \le G$? If yes, how does it follows that $aHa^{-1} = a^{-1}Ha$? If not, it's done?

Furthermore, if $H$ is finite, how does it follows that $N_G(H) = \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$?

What has been done for the second part:

Let $H$ be finite, then $|aHa^{-1}| = |H|$, for every $a \in G$. Does this directly implies that $N_G(H) = \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K=\{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$

> It is necessary to prove that $\{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\} \le G$? If yes, how does it follows that $aHa^{-1} = a^{-1}Ha$? If not, it's done?

Yes, you need to prove $K\le G$

> Furthermore, if $H$ is finite, how does it follows that $N_G(H) = \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$?
>
> What has been done for the second part:
>
> Let $H$ be finite, then $|aHa^{-1}| = |H|$, for every $a \in G$. Does this directly implies that $N_G(H) = \{a \in G: aHa^{-1} \le H\}$?

If $H$ is finite, then the two conditions $aHa^{-1} \le H$ and $|aHa^{-1}| = |H|$ implies $aHa^{-1} = H$. So it is done for the second part.

Comment: Thanks sir. Let me ask something, in general, if $K \subseteq H$ and $H \le G$, then $K \le H$, right?

Comment: No, it is false. For example, $K=\{1\}, H=Z_2$, since the unit element $0$ is not in $K$, so $K$ is not a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Forgot to ask for the additional hypothesis that $K \le G$.

Comment: Yes, then it is true.